# Jquery dialog table width picking previous value

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a Jquery dialog box as shown below:

```
$("#dvPopup").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 450,
        height: 300,
        buttons: [{
            text: "Ok",
            click: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
        }
        ]
    });
```

i have the below function which i call on click of a link in a grid (each row in a table has a link to popup):

```
function showNotes(Id) {
    var grid = $("#NotesPopup").data("tGrid");
    grid.ajax.selectUrl = "/Test/GetNotes?Id=" + Id;
    grid.rebind();
    $("#dvPopup").dialog("open");
    var width= $("#dvPopup .t-grid >table").width();

    if (width > 450) {
        $(".ui-widget-content").css("width", width + 30);
    }
    else{
        $(".ui-widget-content").css("width", 450);
    }
    $(".ui-widget-content").css("height", 'auto');        
}
```

I have a table inside dvPopup and i am setting the width of the pop up depending on the width of the table. My problem is i am getting the width of the previous table loaded and not the current table loaded, when i open and close the same popup twice then it is working as expected. Any issue with the above code?

Comment: Can you show an example somewhere? Why are there two calls to dialog()?

Comment: sorry.. uncommented the 2nd call by mistake while pasting the code here...Edited the question, now there is only one call

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of `.ui-dialog` instead of `.ui-widget-content` ?

Comment: the problem is not about setting it. the problem is with `var width= $("#dvPopup .t-grid >table").width();` it is giving me correct value only from 2nd click and not when i click it first.

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't have a width the first time you ask for it. Can you run the width-checking function as a callback function of dialog() ? That way you know there's something there to get the width of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Cracked it. i used different selector instead of `"#dvPopup .t-grid >table` and used  dialog options that solved my problem . Here is the solution:

```
function showNotes(Id) {
 var grid = $("#NotesPopup").data("tGrid");     
 grid.ajax.selectUrl = "/Test/GetNotes?Id=" + Id;
 grid.rebind();
 $("#dvPopup").dialog("open");
 var width= $(".table_1").width();
  if (width > 450) {
      $("#dvPopup").dialog('option', 'width', test + 30);
 }     
else{
      $("#dvPopup").dialog('option', 'width', test + 30);
 }
  $("#dvNotesPopup").dialog('option', 'height', 'auto');
 }
```